Formula to find the nearest match
I need a formula to cell G2 to find the nearest match based on cell E2 and F2.

My desired result would be Working Offline, since range A2:A13 = E2 (Agent 1) and C2:C13 = F2 (10:00:00), the status should be Working Offline, as the "Available" status for Agent 1 on the left table is at 10:50:39 already, I want the formula to search downwards from the cell F2 criteria, and return the closest match from it.

I'm a bit confused by the question. What would happen if Agent 1 was available at (say) 10:05 - would you want to return "Available"  because that is the nearest match, or are you only interested in times before 10:00, so the answer would be "Working offline" ?

Hi @TomSharpe exactly the answer would be working offline, the goal is to get the nearest match before 10:00

If you have 365:
=LET(
    d, A2:C13,
    f, FILTER(d, E2 = CHOOSECOLS(d, 1)),
    XLOOKUP(F2, CHOOSECOLS(f, 3), CHOOSECOLS(f, 2), "", -1, -1)
)

Notes:

This formula checks the time in F2, and then looks at earlier (or the same) time for the relevant agent to determine the status.

10:52 for Agent 1 would show Available
9:40  for Agent 1 would show a blank since he has not yet logged in.



If you are using a Table, you can simply change the d line of the formula:
=LET(
    d, myTable,
    f, FILTER(d, E2 = CHOOSECOLS(d, 1)),
    XLOOKUP(F2, CHOOSECOLS(f, 3), CHOOSECOLS(f, 2), "", -1, -1)
)


=INDEX(Table2[Status], MATCH(1, (Table2[Agent]=E2)*(Table2[Time]=MAX(IF(Table2[Time] <F2, Table2[Time]))), 0))

Or if you have Excel 365 you can use LET because LET makes everything better:
=LET(
    AgentRange, A2:A13,
    StatusRange, B2:B13,
    TimeRange, C2:C13,
    Agent, E2,
    CutoffTime, F2,
    LatestTime, MAX(IF(TimeRange < CutoffTime, TimeRange)),
    RowIndex, MATCH(1, (AgentRange = Agent) * (TimeRange = LatestTime), 0),
    INDEX(StatusRange, RowIndex)
)


